Has the Vatican ever acknowledged that the New Testament may be missing key parts of Jesus' life?
While acknowledging that the Gospels likely contain most of the key events of Jesus' life...

Has the Vatican ever acknowledged that the New Testament may be missing some key parts of Jesus' life?

Emphasis: The original authors of the Bible, who trace their lineage to the Evangelists, did the best they could to compile accounts of the key parts of Jesus' life, they could not (and in fact did not) bear witness to Jesus' entire life. And consequently, they may have unknowingly omitted key parts of His life.

Has the Vatican ever acknowledged that the New Testament may be missing key parts of Jesus' life?
The Vatican has never acknowledged that the New Testament is lacking in information needed for the salvation of mankind. The New Testament does contain not all the details of Christ's life and even the Vatican would acknowledge that.
Yet everyone knows that the New Testament is lacking only in what transpired in the life of Jesus during the hidden years of his. Obviously, not even the Vatican knows what transpired with Jesus during these years. Whether these are key parts of Jesus’ life is not known.

The unknown years of Jesus (also called his silent years, lost years, or missing years) generally refers to the period of Jesus's life between his childhood and the beginning of his ministry, a period not described in the New Testament.
The "lost years of Jesus" concept is usually encountered in esoteric literature (where it at times also refers to his possible post-crucifixion activities) but is not commonly used in scholarly literature since it is assumed that Jesus was probably working as a tektōn (usually translated as carpenter, but could also mean builder) in Galilee, at least some of the time with Joseph, from the age of 12 to 29.
In the 19th and 20th centuries, theories began to emerge that, between the ages of 12 and 29, Jesus had visited India and Nepal, or had studied with the Essenes in the Judaean Desert.[4][5] Modern mainstream Christian scholarship has generally rejected these theories and holds that nothing is known about this time period in the life of Jesus.
The use of the "lost years" in the "swoon hypothesis" suggests that Jesus survived his crucifixion and continued his life instead of what was stated in the New Testament that he ascended into Heaven with two angels.[9] This, and the related view that he avoided crucifixion altogether, has given rise to several speculations about what happened to him in the supposed remaining years of his life, but these are not accepted by mainstream scholars either. - Unknown years of Jesus

Many Catholic Mystics have added to the information contained within the New Testament, but even with these details, Rome does not decree that Catholics must believe them. The Catholic faithful remain free to not accept them as “gospel” because they remain extra-Biblical and do not carry the same weight as the Divinely inspired Catholic Sacred texts that form the Bible.
The Old and New Testaments contain all the necessary information for all Christians to save their souls! Nothing in this sense is lacking!
This is why superficial knowledge about Jesus is completely lacking in the New Testament. What Jesus looked like, his favourite foods, etc. are thus completely unknown to us.
Besides that, everyone, Catholics and non-Catholics alike, knows the Gospels do not say everything about Jesus's life.
